# Failed to get restore event for content db, SPException: The changeToken refers to a time before the start of the current change log

Tags: 2010, managed-metadata, taxonomy, owstimer

I am receiving the below two errors in the Sharepoint ULS logs when running the timer job "Taxonomy Update Scheduler".

> 02/24/2016 02:19:01.68    OWSTIMER.EXE (0x1B74)                       0x1B70  SharePoint Server               Taxonomy                        0000    Exception   Failed to get restore event for content db 61898e78-cc40-4fc1-9e49-6b20e4aba10a.  Skipping Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The changeToken refers to a time before the start of the current change log.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPChangeCollection.GetChanges(SqlSession session)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPChangeCollection.InitChangeCollection()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPChangeCollection..ctor(SPContentDatabase db, SPChangeQuery query)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPContentDatabase.GetChanges(SPChangeQuery query)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.UpdateHiddenListJobDefinition.CheckForSiteRestore(MetadataWebServiceApplicationProxy proxy, PartitionSettings proxySettings, Dictionary`2& databaseChangeTokens)    334b8111-1c55-4207-9b06-43ab902f27f6

Followed by below:

> 02/24/2016 02:19:01.68    OWSTIMER.EXE (0x1B74)                       0x1B70  SharePoint Server               Unified Logging Service         c91s    Monitorable Watson bucket parameters: SharePoint Server 2010, ULSException14, 044806dd "sharepoint server", 0e00178d "14.0.6029.0", 1f65804a "microsoft.sharepoint", 0e0017f9 "14.0.6137.0", 5136df43 "tue mar 05 22:16:35 2013", 00003e28 "00003e28", 000003c5 "000003c5", f2ce9ddb "spexception:810200bc", 30303030 "0000"    334b8111-1c55-4207-9b06-43ab902f27f6

These 2 errors are repeated for each of the content databases in the farm.

Managed metadata service has not been moved.

No site Collection has been moved.

No item has been moved regarding to search service or metadata service.

Please help me identity what needs to be done to fix the issue.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should attempt to re-mount the Content Database using `Mount-SPContentDatabase` with the `-ClearChangeLog` parameter.

Comment: We are facing the exact same issue. Remounting did not solved the issue. Any other ideas, Trevor? - Thanks